# Looking for simple rules-engine library in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, logic, rule-engine

Does anyone know of a good .NET library rules library (ideally open-source)?  I need something that can do nested logic expressions, e.g., (A AND B) AND (B OR C OR D).  I need to do comparisons of object properties, e.g., A.P1 AND B.P1.  (Ideally, I could compare any property -- A.P1 AND B.P2).

It should store the rules in a database (I've got a lot of simple configurable logic).  And it should have a rule creation/management API.  The management tool would have to inspect the instances to determine which properties are available and which constraints exist.

Thanks!

---

Oh, one more thing.  As a rules-engine, I need to include the concept of Actions (Commands).  These are what execute when the expression returns:

```
If (expression.Evaluation) { actions.Execute(); }
```

So I see a rule as something like:

```
class Rule
{
    Expression Exp;
    Actions[] Actions;
    Run() 
    { 
        if(Exp.Evaluate()) 
        { 
            foreach(action in Actions) 
            { 
                action.Execute(); 
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 46):

Agreeing with will I would say use something from the workflow engine family although not workflow.
Examine [System.Workflow.Activities.Rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.workflow.activities.rules.aspx) Namespace a little bit - it's supported in .Net 3, and built into .Net3.5. You have everything in hand for free to use like you mentioned :

- RuleCondition for conditions ,   RuleAction for actions
- standardized format for describing
  metacode (CodeDom - CodeExpressions)
- you can plugin any kind of complexity
  into that (to tell the truth except
  Linq    and lambdas and so extension
  methods of some kind) via
  TypeProviders
- there's a builtin editor for rule
  editing with intellisense
- as the rule is serializable it can be
  easily persisted
- if you meant to use the rules over a
  database scheme then via typeprovider
  it can be    implemented too

For a starter :
 [Using rules outside of a workflow](http://cgeers.wordpress.com/2008/01/26/using-rules-outside-of-a-workflow/)

Ps.: we're using it extensively and there're much more in that namespace than you ever imagine -> a complete meta algorithm language

And the most important : it's easy to use - really

Comment: great post, that's what we used in the past and found it pretty powerful to leverage the rules engine part outwith of all the windows workflow framework.

Answer (score 18):

Here is a class I have used in the past. It evaluates strings just like eval() does in Javascript.

```
String result = ExpressionEvaluator.EvaluateToString("(2+5) < 8");
```

All you need to do is construct a string to be evaluated from your business objects and this will take care of all the complicated nested logic etc.

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.JScript;

namespace Common.Rule
{
  internal static class ExpressionEvaluator
  {
    #region static members
    private static object _evaluator = GetEvaluator();
    private static Type _evaluatorType;
    private const string _evaluatorSourceCode =
        @"package Evaluator
            {
               class Evaluator
               {
                  public function Eval(expr : String) : String 
                  { 
                     return eval(expr); 
                  }
               }
            }";

    #endregion

    #region static methods
    private static object GetEvaluator()
    {
      CompilerParameters parameters;
      parameters = new CompilerParameters();
      parameters.GenerateInMemory = true;

      JScriptCodeProvider jp = new JScriptCodeProvider();
      CompilerResults results = jp.CompileAssemblyFromSource(parameters, _evaluatorSourceCode);

      Assembly assembly = results.CompiledAssembly;
      _evaluatorType = assembly.GetType("Evaluator.Evaluator");

      return Activator.CreateInstance(_evaluatorType);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the passed JScript Statement and returns the string representation of the result
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="statement">A JScript statement to execute</param>
    /// <returns>The string representation of the result of evaluating the passed statement</returns>
    public static string EvaluateToString(string statement)
    {
      object o = EvaluateToObject(statement);
      return o.ToString();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Executes the passed JScript Statement and returns the result
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="statement">A JScript statement to execute</param>
    /// <returns>The result of evaluating the passed statement</returns>
    public static object EvaluateToObject(string statement)
    {
      lock (_evaluator)
      {
        return _evaluatorType.InvokeMember(
                    "Eval",
                    BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                    null,
                    _evaluator,
                    new object[] { statement },
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture
                 );
      }
    }
    #endregion
  }    
}
```

Comment: I tried your code on my web app. Unfortunatelly dynamic compilation doesn't work with web apps because of permissions on asp temp folder.

Answer (score 8):

None of the open sourced .NET rules-engine have support for storing rules in the database. The only ones that stored the rules in a database are commercial. I've created some UIs for custom rule engines that run off the database, but this can be non-trivial to implement. That's usually the main reason you won't see that feature for free.

As far as I know, none of them will meet all of your criteria, but here is a list of the ones I know of:

Simplest one is SRE
http://sourceforge.net/projects/sdsre/

One with rule management UI is NxBRE
http://www.agilepartner.net/oss/nxbre/

Drools.NET uses JBOSS rules
http://droolsdotnet.codehaus.org/

I personally haven't used any of them, because all of the projects I worked with never wanted to use something built in-house. Most business think that this is pretty easy to do, but end up wasting too much time coding and implementing it. This is one of those areas that the Not Invented Here Syndrome (NIH) rules.

Comment: Drools.NET is not a good idea, depends on a JVM implementation in .Net still in beta, tried it, and it's really not production ready IMHO.

Comment: Has anyone here used SRE?  What was the experience?

Answer (score 7):

Well, since logical expression are just a subset of mathematical expression, you may want to try [NCalc - Mathematical Expressions Evaluator for .NET](http://www.codeplex.com/ncalc) over on CodePlex.

Comment: Hey, that's actually pretty neat.  Although from the examples, I think there could be a more elegant way of evaluating delegate expressions.  This could be the an extension point to insert some reflection on the expression operands.

Answer (score 5):

The official MS solution for this is [Windows Workflow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328.aspx).  Although I wouldn't call it "simple", it meets all of your specifications (which would require an extensive framework to meet, anyhow).

Comment: There is a drawback to the current WF rules engine...it uses a very small subset of codedom expressions but actually does string parsing to generate the underlying code - not the CodeDom classes.

Comment: Initially I was using Drools 3.0.But It doesn't support for .Net Framework 4.5. So Can I use this as a substitute of Drools??

Comment: @ShyamDixit: Sorry, no idea, but I'd pick anything under current development over WF3.  This answer is almost six years old.  Don't make decisions by reading ancient articles/questions/answers.

Comment: Parsing of data can be done by using WF or not?? @Will

Comment: @ShyamDixit: I wouldn't recommend it.

Answer (score 4):

I've used this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/Flee.aspx with success in the past. Give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Workflow Foundation does give you a free forward chaining inference engine. And you can use it without the workflow part. Creating and Editing rules is ok for developers.

If you want to have non-programmers edit and maintain the rules you can try out the [Rule Manager](http://www.acumenbusiness.com/Products.htm).

The Rule Manager will generate a working visual studio solution for you. That should get you started rather quickly. Just click on File \ Export and selecte the WFRules format.

Comment: This is an improved serilizer for the WWF rules engine: https://github.com/chriseyre2000/perfectstorm/tree/master

Comment: The link provided in the answer is broken, please update

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at our product as well at http://www.FlexRule.com

FlexRule is a Business Rule Engine framework with support for three engines; Procedural engine, Inference engine and RuleFlow engine. Its inference engine is a forward chaining inference that uses enhanced implementation of Rete Algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

I would look at Windows Workflow.  Rules engines and workflow tend to start simple and get progressively more complex.  Something like Windows Workflow Foundation is not too difficult to start with and provides room for growth.  [Here is a post that shows it's not too difficult to get a simple workflow engine going.](http://blogs.vertigo.com/personal/dbritton/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=c3cd45fa-ec9d-4874-bfe3-5c6ffe78629a&ID=16&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fblogs.vertigo.com%2Fpersonal%2Fdbritton%2FBlog%2FLists%2FPosts%2FArchive.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe check out [SmartRules](http://www.kontac.net/site/SmartRules/SmartRulesStudio/tabid/78/Default.aspx). Its not free, but the interface looks simple enough.

Only know about it because I've used the SmartCode codegen utility from there before.

Here is an example rule from the Website:

```
BUSINESS RULES IN NATURAL LANGUAGE      

Before
If (Customer.Age > 50 && Customer.Status == Status.Active) {
policy.SetDiscount(true, 10%);
}

After (with Smart Rules)
If Customer is older than 50 and
the Customer Status is Active Then
Apply 10 % of Discount
```

Comment: Defunct now. Try somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a RuEn, an simple open source attribute based Rule Engine created by me:

http://ruen.codeplex.com

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Logician: [tutorial/overview](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/logician.aspx) on CodeProject

Project: [page/source](http://sourceforge.net/projects/logician/) on SourceForge

Answer (score 1):

Try out
http://rulesengine.codeplex.com/

It's a C# Open-Source rules engine that works with Expression trees.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you are trying to do using Lambda expressions (and expression trees) can work for this concept. Essentially, you provide an expression as a string that is then compiled on the fly into a lambda expression/expression tree, which you can then execute (evaluate). It's not simple to understand at first, but once you do it's extremely powerful and fairly simple to set up.

Comment: Right, I understand the use of Lambda expressions and would use them if I were building this from scratch.  But, I'm hoping the guts of this library already exists or can be cobbled together.

Comment: Not that I know of...there are several rules engine type libraries available but none of them are particularly simple and/or efficient and none make use of lambda expressions.

Answer (score 0):

It's not free, as you can't easily untangle it from its BizTalk parentage, but the Business Rules Engine components of BizTalk are a separate entity from the core BizTalk engine itself, and comprise a very powerful rules engine that includes a rules / policy based GUI. If there was a free version of this it would fit your requirements (buying BizTalk just for the BRE wouldn't really work commercially.)