# Business Rule Engine for .NET

Tags: .net, rules, rule-engine, rule

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Looking for simple rules-engine library in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/208659/looking-for-simple-rules-engine-library-in-net)

I'm looking for a rule engine for .NET that is going to be used to control what we're displaying for different types of users etc. on an ASP.NET MVC site, but it is also going to be queried by some of our clients' applications (my guess is that they're going to have to query it through some kind of web service). The engine does not necessarily have to provide a web service API of its own, but it should not be to hard to create a web service that enables us to query it.

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Or of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6444845/rule-engine-how-to-store-rules-to-avoid-parsing-on-edit

Comment: What kind of rules? There are specialized rules for authorization, others for form validation, etc.

Comment: I think it would have to be more of a general business rule engine.

Answer (score 1):

No express "business rules engine" comes to mind, but two technologies to consider are [WWF](http://www.state-machine.com/) and [Hierarchical state machines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663328) (HSM).  See the [.net port of the HSM](http://hessmer.org/dev/qhsm/).